# Can you refactor this code?

Tags: coffeescript, parse-platform, refactoring

How can I refactor this coffeescript method that returns json object?

```
getQuery: ->
  p =
    user:
      __type: "Pointer"
      className: '_User'
      objectId: @model.id
    private: false

  q =
    user:
      __type: "Pointer"
      className: '_User'
      objectId: @model.id

  spec =
    projects:
      collection: "Projects"
      params:
        where: JSON.stringify(p)
      needsFetch: true

    payments:
      collection: "Payments"
      params:
        where: JSON.stringify(q)
      needsFetch: true
```

var 'p' and 'q' are almost same but 'p' has {private: true}

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use underscore, you can extend `p` which is essentially a dictionary:

```
q = _.extend p, {private:false}
```

Comment: It's really awesome. Much appreciated!